# python imaplib parsing gmail

Tags: python, imap

```
import imaplib

usr = 'someuser'
pwd = 'somepwd'

imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
imap_server.login(USER, PASSWORD)
imap_server.select('Inbox')

for message_id in imap_server.search(None, '(FROM "example email.com")')[1][0].split(" "):
    response = imap_server.fetch(message_id, "RFC822.TEXT")
    print response[1][0][1]
```

I want to search for email with a certain subject and from email address.  How do I adjust this code to fit incorporate both check?

Also, once i open a message, I want to search the message for certain content. What
is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't make your entire question boldface. It looks horrid and it feels like you're screaming at me.

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python imap wrapper is very thin - it simply exposes the imap specification, see http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html

in the *fetch* command you can fetch several parts of the mail, you choose to fetch the entire RFC formated mail. You can also search like this:

```
typ, data = imap_server.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Whatever you are searching for")')
```

You already showed how to fetch a mail. When you have the RFC-mail in your hands. Search in this mail, depends on what your criteria is: a regex, something in the headers, ...